# "Парящая раскованностью речь" - так возможно?

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

> Самолично Розанову я слушала по "Свободе" - наилегчайший слог, парящая
> раскованностью речь, королевское милосердие к перебившему (что-то
> уточняющему) ведущему, повествование о том о сём, изящные перескоки -
> да не потому, что мысль теряла, нет! - вопросы сыпались наперебой...

Comment: _**«…парящая раскованностью речь»**_ === Красиво! 

Comment: Красиво, но грамматически неверно.  Парящая свободою/непринужденностью речь. Так разве говорят? И это при том, что возможен правильный П. п.  Парящая в свободном полете речь. "Дай, Пушкин, мне свою певучесть, свою раскованную речь, свою пленительную участь - как бы шаля, глаголом жечь."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут парить - это скорее "быть проникнутым чем-то, источать что-то, стремиться к чему-то (высокому чувству?).

Парить мыслью, духом.

Управление творительным падежом; собственно, этот падеж и указывает на это высокое чувство.

Парить раскованностью, то есть быть раскованным, источать раскованность.

Другое дело, что тут не человеческое существо чем-то парит, а речь парит.

Парящая раскованностью речь, то есть речь парит раскованностью, иными словами, речь ну как бы "сочится" раскованностью, проникнута раскованностью.

Парящая раскованностью речь = проникнутая раскованностью речь.

Comment: Благодарю за оправдание моей косноязычности.